# Modify DNS TXT Record in Domain Control Panel or Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, dkim

I am trying to setup DKIM for email verification and have been asked to add a public key to my DNS.

```
Add public key in your DNS; here is a sample resource record with selector "default":
default._domainkey IN TXT "v=DKIM1; g=*; k=rsa; p=MIG...the_public_key_here...AQAB"
```

I have my domain name pointing to my personal web server at my static up and it is hosted through apache. Do I need to edit some file on the apache server, or add something through the domain.com's control panel?

Comment: Just exactly how do you think Apache is involved in DNS?

Comment: I admit that I don't have much knowledge in this area, but I don't think the question necessarily deserves downvotes. Because the application is being hosted locally, I thought it might have something todo with zone files? None the less, I think the answer to my question is that I need to have the domain registrant add the records. In my situation...domain.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A TXT record is something in the [Domain Name System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Other_applications), Apache is a [webserver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webserver). They are completely unrelated.

You have to ask whoever is hosting the dns service for your domain (it's probably the same entity that's hosting the web server and maintaining the domain name registration) to add that record to the DNS zone of your domain.